# How to align multiple images in "li" on center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am doing a website and I don't know how to do aligning of images wrapped in < li >.

Here you can see the page - http://www.dansid.cz/praginfo/services.php?l=de

I need those images to automatically align on center, how can I do that with CSS?

You can see the CSS etc. by right clicking in Firefox or Chrome and clicking Inspect Element.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: First of all please change <ul id="navlist"> to <ul class="navlist">, because you have multiple ul with same id. And your <a> items is not wrapped with li, only first item. Please fix html errors and try to do as @jacktheripper answer.

Comment: I was playing with the code... Now the items are in li tags. Changed the id to class, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By images in `li`s i assume you're referring to the thumbnails found in your site, you can center them by declaring them `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` and then simply centering them in their container by setting the `text-align:center` property in it, like so:

```
#navlist li {
   display:inline-block;
   *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
}
```

Note: remove the float property.

```
#navlist {
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about the float property. :/ Your code works flawlessly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try on the parent li `text-align: center` for li elements with a width larger than the images

If you want to align the whole ul to the center than I would suggest giving it the attributes:

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: //your width;
```

Comment: I want to align the whole ul to the center, however this does not work. Just added it to the website... :/